# $\mathrm{ann}(R/I) = I$ only when $R$ is unital?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

My professor wrote down that $\sqrt{\mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)} = \sqrt{I}$ for $I$ a proper ideal of $R$. Clearly if $R$ is unital ring we have that $\mathrm{ann}_R(R/I) = I$. So the radical relation is true. However, is this true for when $R$ is not unital?

Comment: I added the "ring-theory" tag to your post.

Comment: Remember to include some extra tag besides abstract algebra, since the later is very general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $RI\subseteq I$, you always have that $I\subseteq \mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)$, unity or not. What identity buys for you is that $1\cdot \mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)\subseteq I$.

Stringing those two together, you'd get $I=\mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)$.

As an example of how this can fail, consider the ring $(x)$ inside $F[x]$ containing the ideal $(x^2)$. You can see that $\mathrm{ann}_{(x)}\big(\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}\big)=(x)$.

Or, for that matter, the ring $2\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z$, and the quotient $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

---

From the containment $I\subseteq \mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)$ you immediately get $\sqrt{I}\subseteq \sqrt{\mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)}$.

Now suppose that $x\in \sqrt{\mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)}$. Then $x^n\in \mathrm{ann}_R(R/I)$, so that $x^nR\subseteq I$. Normally you'd say that $x^n\cdot 1\in I$, and conclude $x\in\sqrt{I}$, but you can't do that here. But (surprise! ) $x^nx\in I$, and indeed $x\in \sqrt{I}$.

Comment: But even if $Ann(R/I) = I$ fails in general, are their radicals equal in general?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 What's your definition of $\sqrt{I}$ in rings without unity? Elements with a power in $I$?

Comment: Yes that is my definition. I am trying to think if it makes a difference if $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 I don't know for sure immediately, but I'm thinking about it. It seems obvious that $\sqrt{I}\subseteq \sqrt{ann(R/I)}$, but I don't know about the reverse.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 I suddenly saw why it is true and added it to the solution. Who is teaching you these things with rings without identity, by the way, if you don't mind mentioning?

Comment: I don't want to say his/her name because my class only has 4 people and is relatively well known. But he does always say $R$ is a ring with unity. I assume he meant that $R$ does have unity but he didn't explicitly state this when mentioning this so I was curious to see if this were true without unity. Your solution is very nice. Thank you.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 But if the ring does have unity, then the statement is utterly trivial :)  I begin to wonder if it would have been for noncommutative rings, but then you would have to redefine the radical again.

Comment: The class is a course on commutative algebra. And yea haha I agree it does become trivial if it is unital.

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing $ann(R/I)$ with $\mathrm{ann}_R (R/I)$. I hope that you don't mind it. Great answer by the way.

Comment: @rschwieb In the non-unital case I think you have to consider $\mathrm{ann}_{(x)}\big(\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}\big)$.

Comment: @stressedout There was just one error as far as I could see.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, that was the intention, and unfortunately the suggested edit missed this :)  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I never change someone's answer when I edit their post, even if there's something in it that is wrong. Although, I did miss that one. Anyway, I edited your post because $\mathrm{ann}$ is prettier than $ann$. :P I have seen users saying all the time that people should stop writing $sin$ or $cos$ instead of $\sin$ and $\cos$. So, I thought maybe the same policy applied to this one too.

Comment: @stressedout Well, that goes without saying. You didn't have to justify your improvement: it is just fine! It's unfortunate though that "ann" does not have a simple counterpart like "sin" and "cos" do.  That was probably my main reason for not bothering with it in the first place.